# Create new LINQ to Entities Objects with associations

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get my head around how to add new records to a table that have a foreign key to another table using LINQ to Entities.  I'll try and explain:

Say I have a simple database with two tables.  For example lets call one LibraryItem and the other LibraryItemStatus.  The LibaryItem has a foreign key to the LibraryItemStatus table so an item can be assigned a status.

My question is how do I create a new LibraryItem using LINQ To Entities and associate it with a status? My code below must be wrong but I cannot find any examples to help.

```
LibraryEntities entities = new LibraryEntities();

LibraryItem item = new LibraryItem();
item.Name = "some name";
item.SomeAttribute = "x";
// What do I do here?
// This seems wrong as I don't want a new status.
item.Status = new Status() { id = 1 };
// This seems wrong as I don't really want to have to query the repository
item.Status = entities.Status.First(s => s.StatusID == 1);
// 
entities.AddToItems(item);
entities.Savechanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "right" way:

```
item.Status = entities.Status.First(s => s.StatusID == 1);
```

or:

```
item.Status = entities.GetObjectByKey(new EntityKey("MyContext.Status", "StatusID", 1));
```

...which will load from memory if the object is already loaded (entities.Status.First will always query the DB).

This is the "hacky but faster way":

```
item.StatusReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyContext.Status", "StatusID", 1);
```

Good: Never any query. Bad: You can't reference item.Status; it will still be null.

**Update**: [There will be a better way to do this in .NET 4.0.](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check for an item.StatusReference property.  That allows some discovery/setting of metadata on the relationship without actually querying for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also map the related table to your ItemEntity in the entitymodel.

I´ve done that for the ProductName in Product -> ProductLanguage in my project published on the url below.

[openticket.codeplex.com](http://openticket.codeplex.com)